# Dealing with big mysql tables to get reports

Tags: php, mysql

I have to get some monthly reports from some big MySQL tables (around 200,000,000 records now). While tables are almost static (previous records are not changed and just new records are added to them)

- is it a good idea to store this huge tables to another database (like
  Oracle or ...) and then run the report queries?
- If it sound rational what are possible destination options?

*In essence I want to know what database specialists do in this situation.*

Comment: Sounds like [OLTP vs. OLAP](http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html) or with SQL Server availability group and read-only replica for reporting

Comment: I guess yes, but I'm searching for a clue to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting your large tables and loading them into some other commercial make and model of RDBMS (like Oracle) is probably a waste of time, and certainly a waste of funds for licensing. Avoid that unless you absolutely need some kind of vendor specific reporting feature that you can't implement in MySQL.

When you mention "monthly" reports, it sounds possible that you need to retrieve time-limited data from these tables. For example, you might have five years' worth of information in the tables, but you only need information from the last six months. You can optimize that kind of thing with appropriate indexes.

For example, you might have a query like this to extract sales for a six month period ending with the month before the present month.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) num_sales, SUM(sale_value) total_sales,
       LAST_DAY(sale_date) month_ending
  FROM sales
 WHERE sale_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 7 MONTH
   AND sale_date < LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND customer_id = 12345
 GROUP BY LAST_DAY(sale_date)
```

If you have an index in your table on the following columns

```
customer_id, sale_date, sale_value
```

this query will be reasonably fast.  It will take a while to build the indexes you don't have, but that's OK because it's a one-time deal.

If you need to have a separate database server for reporting, you should explore setting up MySQL in a master-slave replication setup. That way your reporting server will always be close to up-to-date.  Read this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

One other thing: You may want to use the MyISAM access method for these enormous tables rather than InnoDB. It sounds like you don't, often, UPDATE them. Rather, you INSERT new rows. And, it sounds like your reporting work doesn't absolutely need the most recent rows. So, the InnoDB transaction support isn't helping you much.